# How do you setup 64-bit PHP5 with APC?

Tags: 64-bit, php5

I followed this # [script](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Installing_PHP5#PHP_5.3_.2B_Xdebug_.2B_APC_install_script) on my webhost's wiki to setup a custom install of PHP5, but now theyre telling me they need to move my account to a 64-bit server, and I have no idea how to set this up. APC needs the PHP5 installation to use cgi/fastcgi. I Dunno how that applies to 64-bit or what other considerations need to be made.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this, or by least changing the #[script](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Installing_PHP5#PHP_5.3_.2B_Xdebug_.2B_APC_install_script) to compile using the 64-bit PHP.

I'm learning so much from this site, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

True native 64bit PHP support is very limited, the only version I am aware of is [this one](http://fusionxlan.com/PHPx64.php), there is no official 64bit PHP release. If you are forced to run on a 64bit server, with a 64bit OS, then I would suggest running your web process in 32 bit if possible, otherwise you are likely to find you are not able to do everything you want.

If however your just being put on a 64bit machine, with a 32bit OS, then you can just use 32bit PHP as normal.